# Как в macOS хранятся программы?

Tags: macos

Перешел на мак с винды, не могу разобраться:

1. Я правильно понимаю, что приложения хранятся в /Applications целиком? Т.е. мне достаточно перенести значок из Finder'а в корзину, чтобы удалить его и ни какого мусора не останется?
2. Некоторые приложения (например, игра Warcraft III или Photoshop) создают в Applications целую папку со всеми файлами и это все засоряет Launchpad кучей лишних иконок. Есть ли возможность их убрать оттуда? Чтобы в Launchpad оставался только главный ярлык запуска?

Answer (score 0):

1. Останутся различные настройки в вашей домашней директории в **/Library/Application Support**, **/Library/Preferences** и т.д.
2. Нажмите на иконку и подержите - они начнут "дергаться" и у некоторых будет **Х** в правом верхнем углу. Нажмите на него и иконка будет убрана из **Launchpad**